# How can i show a loader image when i am trying to create a dialog

Tags: ajax, jquery

I am showing some dynamic data in a table on a dialog box when i click any cell of the table it is showing another dynamic data in new table on another popup(dialog box) . this second popup table taking some time to come up after click on cell of 1st table . I want to show a loader image until my second table (dialog box ) comes up....
I searched alot on net but nothing met my situation...

This function get called when i click on cell of first table...

```
// CODE SNIPPET
function access(test1,facilityName,status)
{
    var divString="<table>"+"<tr>"+"<td><table><div id='rfidMove'></div></table></td>"+"</tr></table>";

    //sending some parameters on a jsp page and based on these params getting content of   that jsp here

    $.post("RfidInventory.jsp?","container="+test1+"facilityName="+facilityName+"&                                                                                                                   status="+status, function(data){

    // showing another jsp page data here to make table in this dialog       
         $("#rfi").dialog("destroy");
         $("#rfi").html(divString);
         $("#rfi").dialog({  
         width: '650',
         height: '300',
             zIndex : '3000',
             modal:true, 
         title: "RFID INVENTORY DETAIL",
             overlay: { opacity: 0.1, background: 'black'} 
       });
   $("#rfidMove").html(data);  
});
```

Please help me i already spent a lot of time in this but still hunting for a solution...

Comment: show loader image before the .post, and add callback function() on `success` for hiding the loader image.

Answer (score 1):

Add a *loader* tag somewhere in your DOM, using an animated GIF, and hide it:

```
<div id="#loader" style="display: none;"><img src='loader.gif' alt='loading' /></div>
```

Then display it right before the AJAX call:

```
$("#loader").css("display", "");
$.post(url, function(data) {
    $("#loader").css("display", "none");
});
```

This is the normal way to do it.  You can download a nifty customized animated GIF at this site:  http://ajaxload.info/

*Edit* Try this stuff in Firebug.

**Add loader**

```
$("body").append("<img id='myloader' src='http://www.ajaxprojects.com/db/img16.gif' />");
```

**Hide it**

```
$("#myloader").css('display', 'none');
```

Comment: @vips could have been because there was a typo in my code.  Should work now.  Note, you have to make sure the image *src* path is valid.

Comment: Thanks for replying , I have given right image path but still not able to get rid of this.... is there any jquery plugin issue..? :(

Comment: @vips sounds like there's something else going on.  Are you familiar with Firebug?  That's all I can recommend at this point; play around with the DOM and see why it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

```
var val = 10;
$( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({
    value: val
});

<div id="progressbar"></div>
```

Refer this links:-

http://jqueryui.com/demos/progressbar/

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Progressbar

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/66049/Showing-Progress-Bar-Using-jQuery